# PermissionError: [WinError 5] when renaming files

Tags: python, windows, permissions, renaming

So I'm writing code in Python to go through your current directory, and replace all the files with a certain keyword with a different name.

```
import os

os.chdir("D:\\")

[os.rename(f, f.replace(r'sitka_weather_', 's_w_'))
    for f in os.listdir('.') if not f.startswith('.')]
```

So, it should replace `'sitka_weather_'` with `'s_w_'` in all files that contain `'sitka_weather_'`, right?

But I get this error: `PermissionError: [WinError 5] Access is denied: '$RECYCLE.BIN' -> '$RECYCLE.BIN'`

What does that mean? How do I fix it?

Comment: You forgot to exclude files starting with `$` as well. `not f.startswith('$')`. You probably can't rename the Recycle Bin.

Comment: Might be best to use a normal `for` loop and put the `rename()` in a `try/except` block so you can ignore certain exceptions, like the one you describe. Your code also doesn't check to see if the current item in the list `listdir()` returned is a directory or file.

Comment: Thanks guys it works now.